# Listbox items dont want to stretch

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have problem with styling my listboxitem inside pivot controls. I am trying to stretch it. I am not sure i should mention it because it shouldnt have impact on it, but this listbox is dynammicaly populated by capturing scroll event. I`ve tried this solution, but without success:

```
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                 <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                 <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
           </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Here is my code for the whole pivotItem:

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="Indeks">
            <Grid Name="grd_Content" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <ListBox x:Name="lbx_Index" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Loaded="lbx_Index_Loaded" Template="{StaticResource ListBoxControlTemplate}" Grid.Row="1" Tap="lbx_Index_Tap" Background="{x:Null}">
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" 
                              BorderBrush="Transparent"
                              BorderThickness="0"
                              Background="MediumAquamarine"
                              Foreground="Transparent"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"       
                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              Loaded="ScrollViewer_Loaded">
                            <ItemsPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                    <ListBox.DataContext>
                        <local:ListBoxPart/>
                    </ListBox.DataContext>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Maroon" BorderThickness="2"
                            Padding="5" Margin="5" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="300*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <!--<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="None" Text="Nazwa lekarstwa:" FontSize="14"/>-->
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Left" TextTrimming="None" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Left" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"  Text="{Binding ActiveSubstance}" FontSize="12"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding LevelOfPayment}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding AidAmount}"></TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>
            </Grid>


        </controls:PivotItem>
```

I apperciate any help!

Comment: Your ListBox is aligned to the left, remove the following xaml from the ListBox `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`

Answer (score 0):

Note, you don't need to set the Horrizontal alignment setting to stretch unless it's in a container that overrides it.
By default most XAML controls are set to take up the most space.

Also check that your margins are not shrinking your containers below where you want them. (note you can use negative margins to stretch as well)